# selenium webdriver(chrome) elements differ from those of driver.page_source

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape an article in the medium.

But it failed because selenium.webdriver.page_source doesn't contain the target div.

[E.G.] Demystifying Python Decorators in Less Than 10 Minutes https://medium.com/@adrianmarkperea/demystifying-python-decorators-in-10-minutes-ffe092723c6c

In this site, the content holder div's class is "`x y z ab ac ez af ag`", but this element doesn't show up in `driver.page_source`.

shortcode: below.

It is NOT the kind of timeout problem.
It seems like the drive.page_source is not processed with javascript, but I don't know.

```
ARTICLE = "https://medium.com/@adrianmarkperea/demystifying-python-decorators-in-10-minutes-ffe092723c6c"
driver.get(ARTICLE)
text_soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html5lib")

text = text_soup.select(".x.y.z.ab.ac.ez.af.ag")
print(text) # => []
```

I expect the output of driver.page_source is the same as that of the chrome developer console's elements.

**Update:** I did some experiment. 
I doubted webdriver couldn't get the html source processedby javascript, so I "selenium-ed" the below html file.

But I got "element-removed" html file.

result:

**webdriver and ordinary chrome console are same -> processed**

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("#id").remove();
    </script>

</body></html>
```

**wget / requests -> not processed**

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div id="id">
        test element
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("#id").remove();
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but the first thing I'll try when this happens is change the html parser/ so try changing `"html5lib"` to `'html.parser'` or `lxml'`

Comment: HTML parser: bs4, lxml, html5lib · Issue #318 · astropy/astroquery https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/issues/318


I know that lxml is written in C and rapid, html.parser is very naive, html5lib is richer but little slow.
So this it a problem even though I used html5lib (the most rich one) still I got this same problem.  And I sure tried all of them.

Comment: ah ok. I misunderstood the question. I see what you mean. It's in the dev tool when you look, but it's not in the html source.

Comment: however, I'm not seeing that class in the dev tool console. I'm seeing `x y z ab ac ff af ag`

Comment: what you could do is look through the classes that have `x y z`. maybe for whatever reason what ever you are after is in there?? `text = text_soup.select(".x.y.z")`

Comment: OK, thank you! It seems that article is contained in this "x.y.z". but I'm still wondering why driver.page_source and chrome(attached) element (in developer cosole) are different, I thought that webdriver syncronizes them.

In addition, I encountered similar issues when scraping other sites. This one is the problem that change of class name, but in some of those problems, elements disappear. For example, I cannot push "next page" button.

If anyone solves this problem(how to get "real elements"), please answer this.

Comment: its a good question though. I was under the assumption as you, especially using selenium which pulls the html after its rendered.So I'm curious too now!

Comment: This kind of problem may be better solved by a selenium script with open browsers, instead of scraping backend using bs4.